# Update certain fields based on condition in Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created a Symfony 2 Bundle that supports private messages between users. I gave them the ability to send messages from their `inbox` or `sent` folder to the `trash` one. Messages will be marked as trash through the `isRTrash` and `isSTrash` fields, marked by receiver and by sender, respectively. That is because, being the same message in my database, if I had one single field here, one user marking it as trash, would mark it for the other one, as well.

Now, I want to give them the possibility to `delete` them, too, from their trash folder. Messages won't be deleted, but marked similarly to trash ones, just that they are forever gone from standard user view. I'm having problems with marking them like this, because I have to mark both messages that are sent and received by the user.

I've made the following query in the entity's repository:

```
    public function delete($user, $msg)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->update('PrivateMessageBundle:Message', 'a')
            ->where('a IN(:msg)')
            ->andwhere('a.receiver = :user AND a.isRTrash IS NOT null AND a.isRDeleted = false')->set('a.isRDeleted', true)
            ->orWhere('a.sender = :user AND a.isSTrash IS NOT null AND a.isSDeleted = false')->set('a.isSDeleted', true)
            ->setParameters(
                array('user' => $user, 'msg' => $msg)
            );
echo '<pre>';
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL()); exit;
echo '</pre>';
        return $qb->getQuery();
    }
```

And the output query is `string(196) "UPDATE message SET isRDeleted = 1, isSDeleted = 1 WHERE (id IN (?) AND (receiver_id = ? AND isRTrash IS NOT NULL AND isRDeleted = 0)) OR (sender_id = ? AND isSTrash IS NOT NULL AND isSDeleted = 0)"`

I give as input the curent logged in user and an array of message id's. Then, I check messages that are in trash, are not marked as deleted and have the curent user as receiver or sender and want to mark them as deleted.

The problem is that both conditions are met, and both `SET` are being called, marking a message's `isRDeleted` and `isSDeleted` to true, regardless.

I am very close, but don't know how to make it so that the fields are marked separately, only if their condition is met.

Meanwhile, I'm using a foreach loop, but I think it can be done faster with a query

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach ($msgs as $msgid) {
        $msg = $messages->findOneBy(array('id' => $msgid));


        if ($msg->getSender() == $this->getUser() && $msg->getIsSTrash() && $msg->getIsSDeleted() == false) {
            $msg->setIsSDeleted(true);
            $changedno++;
        } else if ($msg->getReceiver() == $this->getUser() && $msg->getIsRTrash() && $msg->getIsRDeleted() == false) {
            $msg->setIsRDeleted(true);
            $changedno++;
        }

        $em->flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a `CASE .. WHEN` construction but Doctrine doesn't have that in DQL (See the [Grammar](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/)). So you either must use a raw query, something along these lines (*it's pseudo MySQL*) :

```
UPDATE PrivateMessageBundle:Message a
SET a.isRDeleted = CASE
    WHEN a.receiver = :user AND a.isRTrash IS NOT null THEN TRUE
    ELSE a.isRDeleted = FALSE
END, 
SET a.isSSDeleted = CASE
    WHEN a.receiver = :user AND a.isRTrash IS NOT null THEN TRUE
    ELSE a.isSDeleted = FALSE
END
```

... or use two standard queries, one for `isRDeleted` and one for `isSDeleted`, like the one you already did. To be honest I think that's a pretty simple solution in your case, and it looks more *maintenance-friendly* if you ever need to read your code again in six months.

> NB : on a side note, the `->set()` or `->when()` functions in Doctrine (and all the others, in fact) do not follow a specific order; they are just adding properties to the Doctrine query object, and when you call `getQuery()`, a SQL query is made. That means that the following construction :
>
> ```
>  ->when()->set()
>  ->orwhen()->set()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to :
>
> ```
>  ->set()->set()
>  ->when()->orWhen()
> ```
>
> which is why your solution cannot work. There is no condition to be met before `set()` is called (*if I'm not clear, tell me*)

Comment: Yeah I figured out that order doesn't matter in the query. I've also looked for CASE..WHEN statements, but can't find any working solutions for UPDATE, only for INSERT.

Comment: Shouldn't you leave isR/SDeleted values unchanged if conditions are not met ? Seems like you can revive messages by mistake ;). Don't understand why you need to check if value are false since you'll set them to true anyway, any impact on performance ?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc you just have to use a native SQL Query in Doctrine : `return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql, $params);` with `$sql` your query and `$params` the parameters.

Comment: @tchap regarding using two standard queries, that means I'd have to go over the same array of messages twice. I was looking for an alternative to that. Meanwhile, I'm doing a foreach on the array and checking each message, but a single query would be way faster than foreach with the ORM.

Comment: No, I just mean duplicate your update query in your `delete()` function: one with `->where('a.receiver = :user AND a.isRTrash IS NOT null AND a.isRDeleted = false')->set('a.isRDeleted', true)` and one with `->where('a.sender = :user AND a.isSTrash IS NOT null AND a.isSDeleted = false')->set('a.isSDeleted', true)` . It's two `UPDATE` instead of one, it's not a big deal I think, in your case.

Comment: @tchap mind showing it to me? I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try. Either it's invalid, or I get the same problem as in OP, both fields getting updated, regardless.

Comment: It works, just a small typo, 'nul' instead of 'null'